# I cannot debug mvc web application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was using VS community 2017, I removed it and installed vs 2019. There was a problem saying:[image: Installation error]

And when I try to debug with VS 2019 it says:[image: vs error]
I tried to run as administrator. Same problem. I can only run it like :

```
Project>Properties>Debug>Profile:AppName>Launch:Project
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Is VS launched as Administrator? I don't know whether it is still needed, but worth to try.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS2019? Is this your own machine - if a company owned machine might anything be locked down with permissions?

Comment: @d219 Yeah I have tried it. It is my own machine.

Comment: @AndrasCsanyi yeah I `ve run it as administrator

Comment: Here is a [similar issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/167774/packageidmicrosoftancmiisexpressmsipackageactionin-3.html) about "couldn't install Microsoft.Ancm.IISExpress.Msi" on Developer Community maybe you can refer to.

Comment: @KyleWang thank you Kyle but it was not the solution, but I found the solution

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this from [vs community](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/I-cannot-run-my-mvc-core-app/1309172?entry=problem). This issue can occur if you uninstall IIS Express for a specific architecture (x86 or x64) but not the other.

Please check if the following files exist or not:

> C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe

> C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe

Try to uninstall IIS Express from ‘Add Remove Programs’ and then open VS Installer to repair your VS installation.